# in which memory address is stored an element in a multidimensional matrix?

Tags: arrays, matrix, memory-management, hardware, memory-address

If the arrays are stored per rows and char a[100][100][100] is a multidimensional array of characters with a[0][0] which has address 0x1000, which is the address of a[5][5][10]?

The solution is 0xD54E but I don't know how to come up to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements in a multidimensional array are stored in *row major order*, which means that consecutive elements with respect to  the rightmost index will be consecutive in memory.

So, if you have declared and array as

```
char a[L][M][N];
```

- element `a[0][0][0]` will be at a given address `ad`,
- element `a[0][0][1]` will be ad `ad+1`,
- element `a[0][1][0]` will be at `ad+N` as N is the size of a row
- element `a[1][0][0]` will be at `ad+M*N`
- and `a[i][j][k]` is at address `ad+i*M*N+j*N+k`

For your example, i=5,j=5,k=10,N=M=M=100

100*100*5+100*5+10=50510=0xc54de

As address of element `a[0][0][0]=0x1000`, one needs to add it to the previous value, which gives the answer.

Note that the formula `i*M*N+j*N+k` gives the order of element ikj in memory. To convert if in an address, for an array of elements with another type than char, it must multiplied the size of the element. (for instance 4 for an array of `int`s or `float`s).

Comment: If the question were the same but instead of "per rows" it was written "per column", the calculus would have been 10*100*100 + 5*100 + 5 ?

Comment: For row major order, the fastest changing index (ie for elements close in memory) is the last one. For column major order, it is the first, even if this does not really correspond to "columns" in a 3D array. So your formulas is correct.